# VB.NET Option Explicit and Office VSTO Methods designed for Variant Arrays

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, visio

Developing two new Office VSTO add-ins, one for Microsoft Excel and Visio, I ran in to this particular issue.

I have a strong preference to develop in VB.NET with Option Strict On, for the simple reason that it is good practice and saves me a ton of debugging later.

However, a lot of Office object methods like this one for Visio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.getresults

were designed for passing (VBA) Variant Arrays back and forth ByRef (ugh!).

(Because the .net COM interop is quite slow these bulk methods are necessary for a good user experience)

I know how to create these arrays in VB.NET to work across the interop, like:

```
Dim resultArray as Array
resultArray = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Object), 1000)
```

such code works, but of course this kind of late binding violates the Option Strict On rules and opens the door for a whole host of potential bugs.

Is there a way that I can use these Office object methods in a way that works with Option Explicit On?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and insights!

Comment: You are confusing `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict`. The former is `On` by default and requires you to explicitly declare a variable before using it. The latter is `Off` by default and requires strict typing, i.e. no implicit conversions or late-binding.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant Option Strict of course!

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney I have corrected it in the question text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use late binding then you need to use it, which requires `Option Strict Off`. The good news is that you can set it `On` at the project level and then `Off` at the file level for only those code files that require the use of late binding. The further good news is that VB supports partial classes, so you can break a single class across multiple code files. This enables you to put only the code that requires late binding into a partial class with `Option Strict Off` at the file level and everything else in another code file using the project setting of `Option Strict On`. You can break some of your methods up into smaller parts and reduce the amount of code writen with `Option Strict Off` to an absolute minimum.

Comment: Thank you it is very good to know this is possible and a very good solution for the issue!